# Abnormal spacing between abstract and section title

Tags: spacing

The result of the code below shows a spacing between the abstract and the section title that's much larger than the spacing between the title and the paragraph. These spacings should be equal.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000

\makeatletter
\if@titlepage\else
  \renewenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn\else
          {\bfseries\centering\MakeUppercase{\abstractname} \\
          \vspace{\baselineskip}}%
      \fi}
\fi
\renewcommand\section{
  \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}
  {-\baselineskip}
  {\baselineskip}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
    Palavras-chave: Processamento de fluxo distribuído; Apache Flink; Backpressure; Big Data; Estruturas de processamento distribuído; Sobrecarga local; Otimização de recursos.Otimização de recursos. euismod.
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If I remove either of the lines below, the error stops occurring. However, I need my text to be justified and without hyphenation.

```latex
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
```

The problem also stops if I remove the last period inside the abstract. How can I fix this?

Comment: What would be the reason for suppressing hyphenation?

Comment: It is a norm of my institution that I need to follow.

Comment: Amazing! It seems they really want badly typeset theses.

Comment: it really makes no sense to justify the text if hyphenation is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd not get the excess space if you leave a blank line before `\section`.

The reason is that your code adds an unwanted space and the last line of the abstract ends very near to the right margin.

Look for `HERE!` in the code below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000

\makeatletter
\if@titlepage\else
  \renewenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn\else
          {\bfseries\centering\MakeUppercase{\abstractname} \\
          \vspace{\baselineskip}}%
      \fi}{\par}% <-- HERE! 
\fi
\renewcommand\section{% <--- HERE!
  \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}
  {-\baselineskip}
  {\baselineskip}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
 }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
    Palavras-chave: Processamento de fluxo distribuído; Apache Flink; Backpressure; Big Data; Estruturas de processamento distribuído; Sobrecarga local; Otimização de recursos.Otimização de recursos. euismod.
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `%` from  @egreg, what a shock

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Amazing indeed!